# How to Keep Network Namespace after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, cgroups, namespace, container, network-namespaces

I have created a network namespace, but after I have reboot, it've been removed.
I don't found an answer at this problem on the internet, so this is why I'm asking you :
Is there a way to keep a network namespace up with its configuration after reboot ?

Comment: You can't keep *anything* after a reboot. So make a script that creates your namespace(s) with the correct configuration, and execute the script after boot (or as part of the boot process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a script that is run at startup and arrange to have it run by calling it from `/etc/rc.local` or link it (ie. hook it) to another script that runs at startup, or even link it to the init system (init scripts/systemd etc). I found, on some systems, that it works if you add it to `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I will create a script and see what's happen when I restart !